# SSRS2008 - "GroupBy" in .rdl causes losing such data groupby filter repeating others not

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a stored procedure in Sql Server 2008. The logic of the SP is looking like:

```
select Name, Surname, sum(Age)
From (
      (Select t1.Name,t1.Surname,t1.sum(Age) as Age 
       From Table1 t1 
       group by t1.Name, t1.Surname) mt1 
full outer join (Select t2.Name as N,t2.Surname as S,t2.sum(Age) as A        
                 From Table2 t2 
                 group by t2.Name, t2.Surname) mt2 
on mt1.Name = mt2.N and mt1.Surname = mt2.S  
) t
where sum(Age) <= 100
```

So this is returning something like:

```
Name Surname Age
A     B       12
X     B       13
C     D       15
```

I have an SSRS matrix like:

```
Description     Age
<<Expr>>        sum([Age])
```

where Expr is: `IIF(Parameters!check.Value=1,Fields!Name.Value,Fields!Surname.Value)`

Without making any groupby under the related row group in SSRS2008, i am able to see it like tkat. However, when I add a groupby filter depending on "Surname", it somehow removes any Surname that occurring with at least 2 different name. So, I see only `D  15` row instead of:

```
B 25
D 15
```

What is my mistake here? How can I show B 25 at this point as well? (I am supposed to not to change SP if possible)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You shouldn't be filtering the data - you seem to want it all. You should be **Grouping On** the same `Expr` you use for the `Description`.